# Autocompletion of @author in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Intellij Idea. One thing I couldn't figure out yet is autocompletion of the `@author` JavaDoc tag.
When typing `@a` in Eclipse, there are two proposals:

```
@author - author name
@author
```

How do I achieve the first proposal in Intellij (is it even possible?)? And if it's possible, how do I change the template of what is inserted for the author name placeholder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34475894/907576 there I propose to vote up Jetbrains bug-tracker issue "Configure custom author name/email/organization to be used in file templates, completion etc"

Comment: In IDEA 16.3 (at least) it works exactly as you ask.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can work around that via a Live Template.

Go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Live Templates`, click the `Plus Icon Button` (on the right).

In the "Abbreviation" field, enter the string that should activate the template (e.g. `@a`), and in the "Template Text" area enter the string to complete (e.g. `@author - My Name`). Set the "Applicable context" to Java (Comments only maybe) and set a key to complete (on the right).

I tested it and it works fine, however IntelliJ seems to prefer the inbuild templates, so "@a + <kbd>Tab</kbd>" only completes "author". Setting the completion key to <kbd>Space</kbd> worked however.

To change the user name that is automatically inserted via the File Templates (when creating a class for example), can be changed by adding

`-Duser.name=Your name`

to the *idea.exe.vmoptions* or *idea64.exe.vmoptions* (depending on your version) in the *IntelliJ/bin* directory.

[image]

**Restart IntelliJ**

Answer (score 293):

One more option, not exactly what you asked, but can be useful:

Go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File and code templates` -> `Includes` tab (on the right). There is a template header for the new files, you can use the username here:

```
/**
 * @author myname
 */
```

For system username use:

```
/**
 * @author ${USER}
 */
```

[image: Screen shot from Intellij 2016.02]

Comment: IDEA 15 : File > Settings > your steps.

Comment: How can add the current date as well?

Answer (score 30):

Check Enable Live Templates 
and leave the cursor at the position desired and click Apply then OK

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For Intellij IDEA Community 2019.1 you will need to follow these steps :

> File -> New -> Edit File Templates.. -> Class -> /* Created by ${USER}
> on ${DATE} */

[image]

Comment: How to specify Date format in the template?

Comment: There is no direct way to format date so instead of ${DATE} you can use ${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}

Comment: @nanosoft The comment from @Suditi didn't work in intellij 2022.1. I had to create a template variable named `$today$` and assign it the function `date("YY-MM-dd")`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to answer some of the questions here:

Yo can also add predefined variables that take the following values:

```
${PACKAGE_NAME}      Name of the package in which the new file is created
${USER}              Current user system login name
${DATE}              Current system date
${TIME}              Current system time
${YEAR}              Current year
${MONTH}             Current month
${MONTH_NAME_SHORT}  First 3 letters of the current month name. Example: Jan, Feb, etc.
${MONTH_NAME_FULL}   Full name of the current month. Example: January, February, etc.
${DAY}               Current day of the month
${DAY_NAME_SHORT}    First 3 letters of the current day name. Example: Mon, Tue, etc.
${DAY_NAME_FULL}     Full name of the current day. Example: Monday, Tuesday, etc.
${HOUR}              Current hour
${MINUTE}            Current minute
${PROJECT_NAME}      Name of the current project
```

Answer (score 1):

If in File -> New -> Edit File Templates no type of files which you want, or you want to annotate the edited file, like

```
/**
 * Updated by USER.
 * Date: 06.04.2023
 * Time: 9:11
 */
```

You can go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Live Templates`
create a template with variables

```
/**
 * Updated by $user$.
 * Date: $date$
 * Time: $time$
 */
```

and on the right click button `Edit Variables...` and set these variables